# Rails to be consumed by Android app

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, azure

I have a SQL Azure DB and want to bridge it to my Android app.

My question is: can I use a REST API on Rails so it can become that bridge? I would like to know also if I would need anything else beyond the actual DB, the Java app and the Rails API to run the whole service?

And also, in terms of deployment, would it be possible to use an Azure cloud service? Could I deploy it as a website and use the url's (with authentication) to allow access to the data to users of my Android app? If this can't be done in Azure, is there any other hosting provider that do not require a VM to run the API?

Comment: Do you have to use your Rails app with SQL Azure DB or any sql db is ok? Rails should work fine with SQL Azure DB but need some works of setup. On the question: is it possible to build a REST API on Rails so it can become that bridge? The answer is: yes of course. All you need is a instance of virtual machine on Azure. Then you can deploy your Rails app to that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Long Nguyen. I've read a little on the setup, but thanks for pointing that out. I thought I could deploy the Rails API on some sort of cloud/mobile services. If I require a VM, price-wise, would you advice to better deploy on Heroku/AWS?

Comment: Could you please update your question so I can answer it more properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a lot of questions.

1. Can I use a REST API on Rails so it can become that bridge? **Yes you can**. And you only need actual DB, the Java app and the Rails API to run the whole service.
2. In terms of deployment, would it be possible to use an Azure cloud service? **Yes you can use Azure**. And I think you will deploy it as a website and on Android app you can connect to it.
3. If this can't be done in Azure, is there any other hosting provider that do not require a VM to run the API? **Although it can be done in Azure, you have many options that do not require a VM to run the Rails app**. E.g. the most famous PaaS one is [Heroku](http://heroku.com)